# Cube root (Newton's method)

Tags: mathematics, lisp, scheme

Newton's method for finding cube roots states that for any given \$x\$ and a guess \$y\$, a better approximation is \$\dfrac{(\dfrac{x}{y^2} + 2y)}{3}\$.

What do you think of this code for finding a cube root in Scheme?

```
(define (improveguess y x)
  ; y is a guess for cuberoot(x)
  (/ (+ (/ x (expt y 2)) (* 2 y)) 3))

(define (cube x) (* x x x))

(define (goodenough? guess x)
  (< (/ (abs (- (cube guess) x)) guess) 0.0001))

(define (cuberoot x) (cuberoot-iter 1.0 x))

(define (cuberoot-iter guess x) 
  (if (goodenough? guess x) guess
      (cuberoot-iter (improveguess guess x) x)))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at your code for this exercise as well as [the one about approximating the square root](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1396/scheme-use-newtons-method-to-compute-sqrtx) and [the one about finding epsi](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1324/common-lisp-find-epsi), you'll notice a common pattern:

You have a function which performs a single step and a predicate which tells you when you're done. You then apply the stepping function until the predicate is met. When you encounter a common pattern like this, the best thing to do is usually to abstract it. So let's define an `apply-until` function which takes a stepping function, a predicate and an initial value and applies the function to the value until the predicate is met:

```
(define (apply-until step done? x)
  (if (done? x) x
      (apply-until (step x) step done?)))
```

You can now define your `cuberoot` function using `apply-until` instead of `cuberoot-iter`:

```
(define (cuberoot x)
  (apply-until (lambda (y) (improve-guess y x)) (lambda (guess) (goodenough? guess)) 1.0))
```

You can also move your helper functions as local functions into the `cuberoot` function. This way they don't need to take `x` as an argument (as they will close over it) and can thus be passed directly to `apply-until` without using `lambda`:

```
(define (cuberoot x)
  (define (improveguess y)
    ; y is a guess for cuberoot(x)
    (/ (+ (/ x (expt y 2)) (* 2 y)) 3))

  (define (goodenough? guess)
    (< (/ (abs (- (cube guess) x)) guess) 0.0001))

  (apply-until improveguess goodenough? 1.0))
```

Comment: To hoist the constant "variables" in `apply-until` so that you don't have to pass them in over and over, I'd implement using a named `let`:

    `(define (apply-until done? next x)
      (let loop ((x x))
        (if (done? x) x
            (loop (next x)))))`

Comment: Is there a reason to use "let" rather than a nested "define," Chris?

Comment: I mean, I guess I don't understand the syntax of (let ...) in scheme - what does (let loop ...) do?

Comment: I found the answer to my question at http://people.csail.mit.edu/jaffer/r5rs_6.html#SEC36 under the heading "4.2.4 Iteration"

Answer (score 4):

Your `improve-guess` is probably better written like this:

```
(/ (+ (/ x y y) y y) 3)
```

Or, if you define a `mean` function:

```
(define (mean . xs)
  (/ (apply + xs) (length xs)))
```

then you can make `improve-guess` even simpler:

```
(mean (/ x y y) y y)
```

Comment: What does the '.' in '(define (mean . xs)' do?

Comment: @jaresty - that's the scheme notation for a `&rest` argument.